# ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation on Laravel 5.4 with PHP 7

Tags: php, laravel-5, imagemagick

Currently, I have cloned a project. I have PHP 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

The ImageMagick library is installed using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

But when I try image manipulation through this library, it throws the following exception

```
(1/1) NotSupportedException
ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation.
```

How can I install this software with the latest PHP version?

**Note:** I am using Laravel 5.4 in this project.

Comment: After installing restart fpm service
         `service php7.0-fpm restart`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to add `extension=imagick.so` in your `php.ini` file.

- **Location:**

You can do some thing like this for the fastest way:

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

The result is like that:

```
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Or call `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` from some php file to get this information :)

PS: [Source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/313)

Comment: where should i add extension=imagick.so in php.ini ? 
There are many configurations in that file

Comment: Under the extensions that you already have else just at the bottom ;)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem on my computer, and what solved it was:

Instead of installing `sudo apt install php-imagick`, I installed `sudo apt install php7.4-imagick` (or whatever version your PHP installation is).

This, in combination with [Maraboc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46824837/11192976) did the trick for me.