# mews/captcha doesn't show captcha image at localhost

Tags: php, laravel, captcha

I'm testing a html form in Laravel 5.5 and using mews/captcha.
When running at localhost the captcha image won't render. I get a 500 Internal Server in my network tab.

This is part of my view (form) (profile-contact.blade.php)

```
<div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
    <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
        <label for="captcha">@lang('profile.contactCaptcha')*</label>
        <input id="captcha" class="c-input" type="text" name="captcha"
               placeholder="@lang('profile.contactCaptchaInfo')" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="o-grid__col u-6/12">
    <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm u-mt-x5">
        <p id="captcha-image-frame">{!! captcha_img('ah_contact') !!}</p>
        <p id="captcha-image-frame">{!! Captcha::img() !!}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In config/app.php I have included:

in providers:

```
Mews\Captcha\CaptchaServiceProvider::class,
```

in aliases:

```
'Captcha' => Mews\Captcha\Facades\Captcha::class,
```

In composer.json I have included (in "require"):

```
"mews/captcha": "^2.0",
```

In laravel.log I get an error about ImageMagick, I already tried some thing but none worked..

```
ERROR: ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation on Laravel 5.4 with PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824621/imagemagick-module-not-available-with-this-php-installation-on-laravel-5-4-with)

Comment: already saw that one and tried it, but didn't help.. 
I use Laravel 5.5

Comment: please try this `php -m | grep img` and post the output

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/imagick.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/imagick.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/imagick.so in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Have you installed it? `sudo apt install php-imagick`

Answer (score 0):

you might missing the php extension `php-gd`, try install it by `sudo apt install php-gd` or `sudo yum install php-gd` or whatever suits your OS or install method